# Calculate pH of imidazole in solution

Tags: acid-base, equilibrium, ph

I am having trouble understanding how to know how a molecule will reaction in solution. For example, if I have $\pu{1 M}$ of imidazole in solution, how can I calculate the pH of the solution by only knowing that the $\mathrm{p}K_\mathrm{b} = 7.1$?

I assume that imidazole reacts with water (we only work with water solutions) but would the reaction look like this:
$$\ce{C3N2H4 + H2O <=> C3N2H5+ + OH-}$$

So then:

\begin{array}{ccccccc}
\ce{C3N2H4 & + & H2O & <=> & C3N2H5+ & + & OH-}\\
  \pu{1 M} &   &  -  &     & 0       &   & 0   \\
       1-x &   & -   &     & x       &   & x \\
\end{array}

\begin{align}
  K_\mathrm{b} &= 10^{-7.1} = \frac{x^2}{1-x} &
  \implies x &= 2.82 \times 10^{-4}
\end{align}

So then,
$$\mathrm{pOH} = -\log(2.84 \times 10^{-4}) = 3.55,$$
and
$$\mathrm{pH} = 14 - 3.55 = 10.45.$$

Is that the correct way to think when solving problems like this?

Answer (score 1):

seems correct,
confirmed by PubChem: "pH 10.5 for 38 g/L at 20 °C
sourced from: OECD; Screening Information Data Set (SIDS) Initial Assessment Report for SIDS Initial Assessment Meeting (SIAM) 17 Imidazole (CAS number 288-32-4) (2003). Available from, as of July 30, 2018: [https://www.inchem.org/pages/sids.html"](https://www.inchem.org/pages/sids.html%22)